# Proof that continuous function on $ [0, 2]$ has $f(x) = f(x-1)$ for some $ x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Proof that if continuous function on $[0, 2]$ and $f(0) = f(2)$, then for some $x: f(x) = f(x - 1)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)$. The domain of this function is $[1,2]$. Then $g(1)=f(1)-f(0)$ and $g(2)=f(2)-f(1)$. Now use the given facts and the intermediate value theorem.